# imagen png mal exportada a pdf desde itext

Tags: android

estoy desarrollando una app haciendo uso de la libreria itext.

Cuando accedo a una de mis imágenes alojadas en la carpeta drawable, esta no es copiada de manera correcta. Es un logo, y tiene parte transparente. Al incluirla en el documento, el fondo(lo que es transparente) se convierte en negro. Por lo que la imagen si la incluye,pero con el fondo negro.

Este es mi código:

```
      Drawable d = getResources ().getDrawable (R.drawable.logopeq223);
      Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
      ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
      byte[] bitmapData = stream.toByteArray();
      Image imageLogo = Image.getInstance(bitmapData);
      imageLogo.scaleAbsolute(70,40);
      imageLogo.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
      document.add(imageLogo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sergio, si en verdad deseas usar [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) debe ser de esta forma:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30);
//Establece el nombre del archivo .pdf que se obtendra al agregar la imagen.
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:/imagen_a_pdf.pdf"));
document.open();
//Imagen a agregar al .pdf.
Image myImage = Image.getInstance(getClass().getResource("/mi_imagen.png"));
document.add(myImage);
document.close();
```

o similar a tu código, cargando una imagen de /assets:

```
InputStream inputStream = MainActivity.this.getAssets().open("myimagen.png");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
Image signature = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
signature.setAbsolutePosition(70, 40f);
signature.scalePercent(100f);
document.add(signature);
document.close();
```

Aquí puedes ver más **[ejemplos.](http://www.concretepage.com/itext/add-image-in-pdf-using-itext-in-java)**

Comment: Muchas gracias! todo correcto!!!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
> ```

Fijate en esta linea, en ella le dices que le cambias el formato a .jpeg con calidad 100%.

Es decir, ya no es la png con transparencia

Comment: Esto es correcto, lo que sucede aquí es que convierte la imagen a un array de bits, y después la agrega al archivo con  document.add();